# Using dom-repeat over a flat array of strings

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a flat array of strings `protocol.domainNames = ["a", "b", "c"]` and I'm trying to render it inside a component using this template:

```
    <select id="select-domain">
      <option>Select domain</option>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{protocol.domainNames}}" as="domainName">
        <option value="{{index}}">{{domainName}}</option>
      </template>
    </select>
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting a list of `<option>`s that are empty:

[image: list of empty options]

All examples in the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-repeat) show lists containing objects, I can't find anything about flat lists being not supported. What am I doing wrong?

**[EDIT]** So the issue seems to be a bit more complex, see [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Up05qRGK21jTvwIf7T2N?p=preview) for reference. It turns out that pushing new items to `protocol.domainNames` causes problems.

Comment: This is definitely possible. I've set up a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ATA1SwPHa3OOqD3bzoG6?p=preview) with your code. I can see the `value` attribute of the `option` tag is being populated but not the contents of it which is odd...

Comment: @benhjt thank you so much for help, the issue turned out to be a bit more complex than I though. See: http://plnkr.co/edit/Up05qRGK21jTvwIf7T2N?p=preview . The part where I'm pushing stuff to `domainNames` array seems to be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do

```
this.push('protocol.domainNames', item);
```

instead of

```
protocol.domainNames.push(item)
```

so that Polymer can see your data changing.

The relevant documentation can be found at https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-repeat

Comment: Thanks Scott. I haven't seen that anywhere in the docs. Since I'm pushing a lot to this array I ended up with a different solution though. I use a temporary variable, like so: `var temp = []; temp.push('1'); temp.push('2'); temp.push('3'); this.protocol.domainNames = temp`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, I've found out it's best avoided at this point to use Arrays of Strings, since the two way binding doesn't work. I'm serialising my object into arrays of object which then works relatively fine. Issue on the Polymer GitHub. https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1821#issuecomment-110804603